# MySQL: select one result per row against a list of values matching a field, even with no match, and the list includes duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get a result set in mysql where there is one result for each value in a list (with some other conditions), with a bonus if this list can include duplicates. I have run into similar problems before and often have to get creative with solutions, requiring some external manipulation of datasets via code or cli utils.

Example dataset:

| tenant_id | item_id | other_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Five |
| One | Three | Six |
| One | Four | Seven |
| Eight | Nine | Ten |

What I want to do is roughly:

```
SELECT coalesce(item_id, 'none')
from table_name
where tenant_id = 'One'
  and other_col in ('Five', 'Six', 'Five', 'ValueNotInCol');
```

And result set should be:

| coalesce(item_id, 'none') |
| --- |
| Two |
| Three |
| Two |
| none |

In reality, the result set for this query is:

| coalesce(item_id, 'none') |
| --- |
| Two |
| Three |

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this is:

1. Create a temporary table from your data.
2. Do a left join from your tmp table to the table you want to search.

I sought a solution that didn't require writing to the db, but this is sufficient.